# Magento 2.3.3 create popup

Tags: model, popup, modal-popup

How to create a popup?

I want to create a popup for every page unless the customer clicked close.
I want to show a popup with the cms block content.

I am not sure what to do or how to start I have looked at few from `inchoo` and here but they both didn’t help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the module also can manage Popup settings from Admin Panel. You can download from [Github](https://github.com/vrajeshkpatel/magento2-module-popup)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way..!

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Popup" name="popup.config" template="VENDOR_MODULE::popup.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Block/Popup.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Popup extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getShowPopup()
    {
        $showpopup = $this->_cookieManager->getCookie('showpopup');
        if(!empty($showpopup) && $showpopup == 'no')
            return 'no';
        else
            return 'yes';
    }
}
```

**app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml**

```
<?php if($block->getShowPopup() != 'no'): ?>
    <div id="popup-modal">
        Hiren Goswami
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal', 'mage/cookies'],function($, modal, cookies)
        {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: 'mymodal1',
                    click: function () 
                    {
                        console.log('Continue...')
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

            $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal').on('modalclosed', function() 
            {
                $.cookie('showpopup', 'no', { path: '/' });
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This isn't loading up, I have followed this but not displaying
I have the block, layout, template not doing

Comment: check template(popup.phtml) file is called or not ??